# Angularjs: attaching a click event in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a great tree directive here.
 Original: http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/

I am trying to attach a click handler. I added it to the `p` element as below, but it is not working. What is wrong:

code http://jsfiddle.net/tHh5M/2/

```
module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {family: '='},
        template: 
            '<p ng-click="testme()">{{ family.name }}</p>'+
            '<ul>' + 
                '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' + 
                    '<tree family="child"></tree>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
            var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                if(!compiledContents) {
                    compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                }
                compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                         iElement.append(clone); 
                });
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.testme = function () {
                console.log('testme')
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you return from the compile function is the link function. Get rid of the link property and move the `scope.testme` up into the function returned from the compile function.

```
    compile: function (tElement, tAttr) {
        var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
        var compiledContents;
        return function (scope, iElement, iAttr) {
            if (!compiledContents) {
                compiledContents = $compile(contents);
            }
            compiledContents(scope, function (clone, scope) {
                iElement.append(clone);
            });
            scope.testme = function () {
                console.log('testme')
            };
        };
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tHh5M/3/

Comment: +1.. thank you so very much :-) also, a followup qn. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125551/angularjs-understanding-a-recursive-directive