# AngularJS recursive directive with a dynamic HTML template

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest, recursion

I have a really hard task here. I am working on an `AngularJS` web app, which is capable of sending different HTTP methods to our project's `Restful Web Service` and receiving responses in JSON. Basically it looks like this:

[image]

You can create some `REST resource` from this application. Let's say an `exam`. To create an exam - you pick a resource from a list of available resources. This triggers a function, that sends a request to `localhost:8080/STEP/api/explain/resorceName` and gets a description for this resource. Description looks like this:

http://jsonblob.com/534fc022e4b0bb44248d6460

After receiving a response - I start building input fields like follows (`allFields` - array of field objects for this resource, `enumValues` - enum values for resource's field if it's property `isEnum = true`):

```
<div ng-repeat="field in allFields">
    <div ng-show={{!field.isEnum}}>
        <p ng-show={{field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}*: </p>
        <p ng-show={{!field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}: </p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="updateEntityResource[field.name]" ng-change="getUpdateEntityAsText()"
            class="form-control" placeholder="{{parseClassName(field.type)}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-show={{field.isEnum}}>
        <p ng-show={{field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}*: </p>
        <p ng-show={{!field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}: </p>
        <select ng-model="updateEntityResource[field.name]" ng-change="getUpdateEntityAsText()" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            <option ng-repeat="enumValue in field.enumValues" label={{enumValue.name}}>{{enumValue.ordinal}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem. I need to create a recursive directive, which would be capable of generating fields in such maner as described above for every resource's field that has "restResourceName" not null. To get all it's fields you just send a request to localhost:8080/STEP/api/explain/restResourceName and get similar JSON response as shown above, which is then used to build HTML elements for inputing values into model.

How can this be achieved using angular recursive directive?

Comment: Maybe check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125551/angularjs-understanding-a-recursive-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I created [a small plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3oSUIxXAC9Xy3v2rPAF?p=preview) that generates a form based on a description in a js object.

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div my-form form-config="allFields" model="model1"></div>
  <div my-form form-config="allFields" model="model2"></div>

  Model 1: {{model1|json}}<br>
  Model 2: {{model2|json}}<br>

</body>
```

myForm.html (template):

```
<div ng-repeat="field in formConfig">
      <div ng-show={{!field.isEnum}}>
        <p ng-show={{field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}*: </p>
        <p ng-show={{!field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}: </p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model[field.name]">
      </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.allFields = [
    {
      "isEnum": false,
      "isRequired": true,
      "name": "First name"
    },
    {
      "isEnum": false,
      "isRequired": false,
      "name": "Last name"
    }
    ];

  $scope.model1 = {};
  $scope.model2 = {"First name":"John","Last name":"Doe"};
});

app.directive('myForm', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      formConfig:"=",
      model:"="
    },
    templateUrl:"myForm.html",
  };
});
```

What is it exactly you are stuck on?

Comment: I can't make a directive which could do the thing you did in a plunkr + is the field has restResourceName - it should be called recursively for each of it's fields.

Comment: Do mean you have fields containing fields?

Comment: Yes. which can contain fields and so on

Comment: If the field itself is a resource (one from the list we choose at the beginnig - it should be "opened" the same way as original root resource)

Comment: I have updated my answer, it's now a directive. For the recursive part, is the end result still a "flat" form of inputs ?

Comment: It still doesn't fit :(
It should also atach a ng-model of a current field to a root model like this:

rootModel.field -> rootmodel.field.nestedField - > rootModel.field.nestedField.nestedField2 -> etc. 

That should be a realy complicated directive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have seen this already, but this sounds a lot like what you are talking about. 
http://jsbin.com/acibiv/3/edit

The guy who wrote it up explains it a bit here:

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/