# Why is a parent controller's $scope not accessible from a (child) directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

From reading [Scopes (Part 2 of the AngularJS - from beginner to expert in 7 steps series)](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-scopes.html): A `$scope` can contain both data and functions available in a view. If AngularJS cannot find a function on a local `$scope`, the containing (parent) `$scope` will be checked for the property or method there.

Given my implementation of a directive's compile function (based on [Angularjs: understanding a recursive directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125551/angularjs-understanding-a-recursive-directive)):

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

    var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
    console.log(contents);
    var compiledContents;

    // postLink function.
    return {
        post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            if (!compiledContents) {
                // Get linking function.
                compiledContents = $compile(contents);
            }

            // Link scope and the template together.
            compiledContents(scope, function(clone) {
                iElement.append(clone);
            });

            scope.myEvent = function() {
                console.log("My Event handled!");
            };
        },
        pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { }
    }
}
```

In the code above, I have attached a function to the `$scope` of the **instance element**, and this is successfully called from the view. However I expected to be able to move the function definition from the **instance element** scope and into a parent controller's `$scope`:

```
angular.module('Myapp').controller('MyParentController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.myEvent = function() {
                    console.log("My Event handled!");
          };
}]);
```

However the parent controller's function is never called even though it is a parent of the directive for which I provided my own implementation of compile.

Updated to add code for the directive:

```
angular.module('Myapp').directive("my-directive", function(RecursionHelper) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: '=data'
        },
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
            return RecursionHelper.compile(tElement, tAttributes);
        }
    };
});
```

..and the RecursionHelper:

```
angular.module('Myapp').factory('RecursionHelper',
    ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
         var RecursionHelper = {
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

                var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
                var compiledContents;

                return {
                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                        if (!compiledContents) {
                            compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                        }

                        compiledContents(scope, function(clone) {
                            iElement.append(clone);
                        });
                    },
                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { }
                }
            }
        }
        return RecursionHelper;
    }]);
```

Comment: can you share complete directive code

Comment: @HarishR - OP updated to include full directive code.

Comment: is `$scope.myEvent` called via `ng-click`? could you pls paste your directive's template here as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your scope to

```
    scope: {
        data: '=data'
        myEvent: '=myEvent'
    }
```

and then on your directive change this

```
       angular.module('Myapp').directive("my-directive",
```

to
           angular.module('Myapp').directive("myDirective",

then pass the function as in

```
 <my-directive data="scope-data" my-event="scope-event-function()"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

because your directive has an isolated scope, you can only access `data` in parent scope.

```
scope: {
    data: '=data'
},
```